# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - serving node.js app from monorepo (subdirectory)

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a mono-repo with various shared assets folders and a node.js "webapp" folder.

I would like to serve the "webapp" folder however it appears the default behavior of ELB is to look for a package.json in the root.

How can configure Elastic Beanstalk to serve the application from the "webapp" sub directory?

I assume I can set a .ebextensions config but I cannot see anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, from hours of forum reading, the solution was to create a `Procfile` in the root directory and use that to run `npm start` for example:

```
web: cd webapp && npm start
```

Comment: Does that mean you deploy the whole monorepo to EB, but only one subfolder is being used? In that case, you might as well init the EB app inside the subfolder? EB doesn't need to know all the other sibling folders, I suppose?

Answer (score -2):

I moved the `.elasticbeanstalk` folder inside the sub directory and it started working without any further changes

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30583514)